# Pinning element in ScrollViewer whilst adding content

Tags: windows, xaml, windows-phone, windows-10

I have the following setup in a Universal app -

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="ContentScrollViewer"
              Grid.Row="1"
              BringIntoViewOnFocusChange="False">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ListView x:Name="TopContent" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />

        <Grid x:Name="ContentToPin" Grid.Row="1" Height="400" />

        <ListView x:Name="BottomContent" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />

    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

When Loading neither listview is populated and the ContentToPin aligns correctly with the top of the screen. However when I start to populate the TopContent listview the ContentToPin element is pushed down the screen.

```
|                        | <- TopContent ListView populated off screen.
|                        |
------------------------- <-Top of screen
|                        |
|                        | <- ContentToPin
|                        |
```

So the TopContent is loaded offscreen, an indicator is then displayed in the ContentToPin indicating more content is available above so the user can pan down to view TopContent.

What is the best way to populate the TopContent ListView whilst keeping the top edge of ContentToPin to the top of the page?

*Note I don't want to set a height for the TopContent ListView.

I have attempted to use SizeChanged event handler on the TopContent ListView to adjust the ScrollViewers position but this just produces a jerky behavior.

```
   private void TopContentListViewOnSizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var heightChange = e.NewSize.Height - e.PreviousSize.Height;
        this.ContentScrollViewer.ChangeView(
            null,
            this.ContentScrollViewer.VerticalOffset + heightChange,
            null,
            false);
    }
```

Comment: You want the scrollviewer to extend the scrollable area upward while keeping it positioned at "ContentToPin" ? did you achieve this yet without being jerky?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your `Grid` is moving down the screen is because your `ListView` is increasing it's size, and therefore, the `RowDefinition` that is it's container is being expanded. Thus, pushing the other `RowDefinition` elements downwards.

Now, as to resolving the problem, there are a couple of things I can think of, however it is **unclear** exactly what you are trying to achieve here. Nonetheless, here are my two cents.

You can change your `Grid` and allow it to populate **2** `RowDefinitions` instead of one, this will ensure that the content remains *pinned* to the top of the screen.

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentToPin" Grid.RowSpan="2" Height="400" />
```

Otherwise, it may even be a better solution to move your `Grid` **outside** of the parent `Grid`, like this:

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <Grid>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                ...
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <ListView ... />
            <ListView ... />
        </Grid>

        <Grid x:Name="ContentToPin">
            ...
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
<ScrollViewer>
```

Please note that the above code is just an example.

Comment: I've updated the questions trying to give a better description of the behavior I'm trying to achieve. I've also attempted to adjust the ScrollViewers VerticalOffset on the SizeChanged event for the TopContent ListView but this just causes the elements to jump around on the page.